# PHP Insert Statement Inserting Array Values Twice

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I have a group of checkboxes each with the name attribute "question_id[]". Additionally I have a selectbox that passes a singular value of survey_id. These values are passed via the form to:

$survey_id= $_POST['survey_id'];

```
foreach($_POST['question_id'] as $question_id) {

    $sql=("INSERT INTO questions_questionnaires (question_id, survey_id) VALUES ('$question_id', '$survey_id')");

    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

}
```

Each value in the 'question_id' array is being inserted twice into the DB. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `mysqli_query` twice:

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Remove the first one (outside of the `if`) and it should be okay.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Not enough coffee this morning. Thanks. That did the trick.